# Mysql query select all dates (day & month only) within next 45 days

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I need to select all dates (day & month) within the next 45 days (regardless of year). The below query has stopped working. Like literally started returning no rows when there is definitely data there.

Is there another way to do this query? Happy to check records within a php loop if needed.

Essentially I need to show all records within the next 45 days, even if the year has lapsed.

```
SELECT
   p.*,
   c.company 
FROM
   products p 
   LEFT JOIN
      customers c 
      ON c.id = p.id 
WHERE
   DATE_FORMAT(p.service_date, '%m-%d') >= DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), '%m-%d') 
   AND DATE_FORMAT(p.service_date, '%m-%d') <= DATE_FORMAT((CURDATE() + INTERVAL 45 DAY), '%m-%d') 
   AND c.email_service = 1 
ORDER BY
   p.service_date ASC
```

Comment: How does the `service_date` column data look like ? What is its datatype.

Comment: Just a standard date field - ie '2017-11-29' would still be within the next 45 days in this query as I don't care about the year.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked this out with php

```
// Get the dates m-d for the next 45 days
for ($i = 0; $i <= 45; $i++) {
    $days = '+' . $i . ' days';
    $date = date('m-d', strtotime($days));
    if ($i != 45) {
        $DateQuery .= "'$date',";
    } else {
        $DateQuery .= "'$date'";
    }
}
```

and Inserted the dates I needed directly into the query

```
    SELECT
       p.*,
       c.company 
    FROM
       products p 
       LEFT JOIN
          customers c 
          ON c.id = p.id 
    WHERE
       DATE_FORMAT(p.service_date, '%m-%d') IN 
       (
           $DateQuery
       )
       AND c.email_service = 1 
    ORDER BY
       p.service_date ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why your original query was utilizing `Date_Format()` on a column (`service_date`), already stored in MySQL Date type, for range comparisons. It is not able to use any indexing (if defined) either.

You simply need to add/subtract `Interval` to the date:

```
SELECT
   p.*,
   c.company 
FROM
   products p 
   LEFT JOIN
      customers c 
      ON c.id = p.id 
WHERE
   p.service_date >= CURDATE() 
   AND p.service_date <= (CURDATE() + INTERVAL 45 DAY) 
   AND c.email_service = 1 
ORDER BY
   p.service_date ASC
```

Comment: I am using date format so I can ignore the year. This query will only look at dd-mm-yy within the next 45 days. I need to see dates within the next 45 days even if the year has expired.

Comment: @Jeff what do you mean by year has expired. My query will work 45 days + current date, irrespective of the year.

Comment: so records I want to select with date within next 45 days regardless of year would be for example.

'2017-11-29'
and
'2018-11-29'

Comment: The above will always query based on the current year.

Comment: @Jeff try running the query. I dont see why my query will work for a year only. Unless the data in your table is not really date type. Best would be to put up a fiddle of small sample data showcasing the exact problem. You can set it up here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/

Comment: I was using your query before but client wants to see all dates in next 45 even if the year was last year. The CURDATE() will look at the current year only.

Comment: @Jeff please setup the fiddle. Apologies but words are not making much sense.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this problem is to use [`DAYOFYEAR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofyear). The difficult part is dealing with the case when you are within 45 days of the end of the year, in which case you have to split the check to see if the date is between now and the end of the year or the beginning of the year and now + 45 days; otherwise you just check if the day of the year is between now and now + 45 days. Try replacing your condition with this:

```
CASE WHEN DAYOFYEAR('2018-12-31')-DAYOFYEAR(NOW()) < 45 THEN
         DAYOFYEAR(p.service_date) BETWEEN DAYOFYEAR(NOW()) AND DAYOFYEAR('2018-12-31') OR
         DAYOFYEAR(p.service_date) BETWEEN 1 AND DAYOFYEAR(NOW() + INTERVAL 45 DAY)
     ELSE
         DAYOFYEAR(p.service_date) BETWEEN DAYOFYEAR(NOW()) AND DAYOFYEAR(NOW() + INTERVAL 45 DAY)
     END
```

Your full query should then look like this:

```
SELECT
   p.*,
   c.company 
FROM
   products p 
   LEFT JOIN
      customers c 
      ON c.id = p.id 
WHERE
    (CASE WHEN DAYOFYEAR('2018-12-31')-DAYOFYEAR(NOW()) < 45 THEN
              DAYOFYEAR(p.service_date) BETWEEN DAYOFYEAR(NOW()) AND DAYOFYEAR('2018-12-31') OR
              DAYOFYEAR(p.service_date) BETWEEN 1 AND DAYOFYEAR(NOW() + INTERVAL 45 DAY)
          ELSE
              DAYOFYEAR(p.service_date) BETWEEN DAYOFYEAR(NOW()) AND DAYOFYEAR(NOW() + INTERVAL 45 DAY)
          END)
    AND c.email_service = 1 
ORDER BY
    p.service_date ASC
```

If you are worried about leap years, you could change the `DAYOFYEAR('2018-12-31')` to `DAYOFYEAR(CONCAT(YEAR(NOW), '-12-31'))`

Comment: Hi @nick - getting an error but im out my depth so not sure if I have put the query together properly

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE WHEN DAYOFYEAR('2018-12-31')-DAYOFYEAR(NOW()) < 45 THEN DAYOFYEAR' at line 6

Comment: what should the full query look like. I cant get it working?

Comment: @Jeff sorry about slow reply - was sleeping. I've added what the full query should look like although I see you've solved the problem yourself in the meantime.